# how to code and run extension in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am new to firefox development. I have downloaded the SDK for firefox and a standalone developer version of firefox. I don't know how to enter and test my code the way we do in .net.
I have copied [User Agent code](http://techpatterns.com/forums/about304.html) from [this XML](http://techpatterns.com/downloads/firefox/useragentswitcher.xml).
I want to add some variations in it and want to run then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting started with the Addon SDK, your first stop should be the [*'getting started'*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials#getting-started) documentation from SDK's documentation.